# Waterproofing options- Monolithic foundation

Tags: waterproofing

Water in Basement- Best options

So I moved into a new house last fall. Early summer we had a huge rain, like 4 inches of rain in a few hours. The prior owners hadn't maintained the gutters, so we worked to cleaning them out, installing gutter guards and running new corrugated piping to take the water to a ravine behind the house. A few weeks ago we had another big rain and luckily only water in the basement was a small amount that was more weeping that could easily be solved with a towel. We want to finish off this unfinished basement in the future, so we want to make it so we have 0 water coming in and also ensure that even a huge flood will not causes issues.

We have had a few waterproofing companies come in to give us a quote. Both have told us that we have a monolithic foundation, so the typical solution of digging out and installing a under the cement at the base of the wall water drainage system would damage the foundation and allow the house to have sinking issues in the future. They all have recommended a system, normally called Drytrak, that would sit on top of the basement floor and utilize weeping holes and plastic on the walls to divert any water to a sump pump and be taken out that way. They both said that the cost to dig out and treat the outside would be very high and not something they would recommend, due to the cost. One quote was for $11.5K, using just the Drytrak system and another was $23K, using a dual drytrak and under the middle of the ground (apparently far enough away to not damage the foundation) drainage tubing to take the water to a sump.

I wanted to see if this truly is the best option and if this really would protect my cinder block foundation, since it's still letting the water coming on, but just giving it a better place to go and hopefully not letting the cinder blocks fill up with water

Thanks for reading my long post!

Comment: how about french drain

Comment: You could try grading the soil around your house to flow water away better, and plant thirsty plants instead of just grass, but if you want absolute protection, yeah the pump is the way to go

Comment: How old is the house?

Comment: @Huesmann house was built in 1991

Comment: You say you have a slab with CMU walls?  Where does the water come in—through the walls, or through the joint at the slab?

Comment: So we have cinder block walls, that sit on top of the floor, since you can see the full cinder block. The water comes in thru where the block and the floor meet up.